# create a calculated column in dataframe using a condition

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

My Dataframe in Python has the following Numerical Data
mydf =

```
mydate     mytime                  myopen                 High                   Low                    myclose
---------- ----------------------- ---------------------- ---------------------- ---------------------- -----------
2019-04-15 1900-01-01 15:25:00.000 1675.75                1679.75                1673.35                1673.35
2019-04-15 1900-01-01 15:25:00.000 142.75                 142.8                  142.25                 142.45
2019-04-15 1900-01-01 15:25:00.000 387                    387.5                  385.7                  387.05
2019-04-15 1900-01-01 15:25:00.000 54.7                   54.7                   54.45                  54.45
2019-04-15 1900-01-01 15:25:00.000 1026.1                 1028                   1026.1                 1027.15
2019-04-15 1900-01-01 15:25:00.000 53.65                  53.75                  53.5                   53.7
```

I need to create a calculated Column called newcol, whose calculation will be based on a Condition. Condition being which of the columns have Higher Values - myopen/ myclose. for Higher values I believe **np.fmax** function is good for my case.
So, **For each record** in the above df...

```
If myopen >= myclose:
mydf['newcol']= myopen X 6 + 4 * High + (High - myclose)
else:
mydf['newcol']= myclose X 3 + 4 * myclose + (myclose - myopen)
```

It's my belief that the above can be attained by traversing mydf, 
However I also feel that there should be a more efficient to accomplish this.

I would appreciate help on the above as I am still a newb.

Thx in adv.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Apart from `numpy.where` you can use `loc` function with condition to achieve this as shown below:

```
df.loc[df.myopen >= df.myclose, 'new_col'] = df.myopen X 6 + 4 * df.High + (df.High - df.myclose)
df.loc[df.myopen < df.myclose, 'new_col'] = df.myclose X 3 + 4 * df.myclose + (df.myclose - df.myopen)
```

Alternatively, you may use `dataframe.apply` in case if functions get more complicated. e.g.

```
def open_close_calculation(df):
    if df.myopen >= df.myclose:
        return df.myopen X 6 + 4 * df.High + (df.High - df.myclose)
    else:
        return df.myclose X 3 + 4 * df.myclose + (df.myclose - df.myopen) 

df['new_col'] = df.apply(open_close_calculation, axis=1)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `np.where`:

```
more_than = ...  # value of new column when more
less_than = ...  # value of new column when less

mydf['newcol'] = np.where(mydf['myopen'] > mydf['myclose'], more_than, less_than)
```